How can I vertically center the question mark on the left of this theorem-like environment?
How do I modify the following environment to make the question mark appear vertically centered (whose spacing depends on the text length)?

Here is the code that produces that question box:
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\NewEnviron{myq}
{
    \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{gray!10}{
        \tikz\node[
        font=\fontfamily{ppl}\fontsize{1cm}{1.2cm}\selectfont]{?};
        \parbox{\textwidth}{
        \vspace*{-2mm}
        \begin{question}
                \BODY
        \end{question}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}


\begin{myq}
  Here is some question in a gray box, 
  with a question mark to the left of it.     
  The thing is, I'd like the question mark to be 
  centered vertically within the box. How do I 
  do that?
\end{myq}

\end{document}

Originally, I had a question on how to put text in a box and how to shade it gray and how to put a large question mark to the left, but I figured out all of those (after searching online). Making the question mark vertically centered is the last part I haven't figured out yet.

Try this code.
Inserts the sign ? into a parbox with a width of the sign, calculated using the calc package. Places the two parboxes side-by-side with a total width of \linewidth.

\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{showframe}% only to show the margins

\usepackage{calc}% added <<<<<<<<<<<
\newlength{\signwidth}  % added <<<<<<<<<<<
\setlength{\signwidth}{\widthof{\fontfamily{ppl}\fontsize{1cm}{1.2cm}\selectfont ?\ }}

\newtheorem{question}{Question}

\NewEnviron{myq}
{\noindent\fcolorbox{black}{gray!10}{%
        \parbox{\signwidth}{% added <<<<<<<<<
            \vspace*{-2mm}% OPTIONAL <<<<
            \tikz\node[font=\fontfamily{ppl}\fontsize{1cm}{1.2cm}\selectfont]{?};
        }
        \parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-\signwidth-\marginparsep-2\fboxrule}{%changed <<<
            \vspace*{-2mm}
            \begin{question}
                \BODY
            \end{question}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \begin{myq}
        Here is some question in a gray box, 
        with a question mark to the left of it.     
        The thing is, I'd like the question mark to be 
        centered vertically within the box. How do I 
        do that?
    \end{myq}
    
\end{document}


I just noticed that the environment doesn't automatically start a new line. I found that by replacing \noindent with \par\noindent\ignorespaces fixes the issue

And thank you! Your answer was extremely helpful to me.
